# Not using line continuation at all, but got "SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character". Beginner level

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm beginner of Python. I've got this error. What's wrong with this code.
I've never used line continuation character. Thanks in advance.
(Windows 10, Atom editor, execute on cmd)

```
def input_eaten():
    input_test = print('Enter somethings eaten in last 24 hours: ')
    return input_test

eaten_some = input_eaten()
print('dairy' in eaten_some.lower())
```

Comment: Your code as it is posted does not have any line continuation at all indeed. Please post your code in its entirety so we can help.

Comment: It's all. As execute this code, will input somethings include 'dairy'. then if it gives "True" result, then I can continue next step. But I cannot continue now.

Comment: If you read the error message further, it tells you where the error is. It tells you the filename and the line number.

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 1
    C:\Python34\edX\function\M1_RCA.py
                                     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character //// it's all of error message

Comment: def how_many():
    requested = input("enter how many you want: ")
    return requested

number_needed = how_many()
print(number_needed, "will be ordered") ///This code gives the same error. Simple code, but cannot find what's wrong....

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to figure what do you want to do with this code really. But if you want to:

1. Let user write what he was eating.
2. Check, if in sentence given by user is word dairy (no matter character case), and if so, return True.

Then there are you problems. First, if you want your code to let user write something you need to use this:

```
input_test = input('Enter somethings eaten in last 24 hours: ')
```

Input is for letting the user write something for the code. print is for printing something on the screen, so you can't return print. You can return however a string, and then give it to some variable, and then print this variable.

```
def input_eaten():
    input_test = input('Enter somethings eaten in last 24 hours: ')
    return input_test


eaten_some = input_eaten()
print('dairy' in eaten_some.lower())
```

I hope I helped you. If not, let me know what exactly do you want your program to do. Keep practice and good luck :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I cannot fix the error. Actually I've got the same error message with other codings. I mean that I coded several simple code, and got the same error. But when I copy those code to PyCharm, no errors. That's why I am confusing.

Comment: If that\s the case then I'm very sorry, but I cannot help you. I'm not a pro at programming, I started few months ago and I never meet this error. Maybe it's not about the code, but about IDE settings (or system settings)? Did you try to not copy, but just write the same thing I wrote and check if this work? Try go deeper into Google, I hope you will find answer to your problem soon.